# How to include the first few items of a numpy array with python

Tags: python, numpy, row

I have array d,  I want array d2
The rows do not have the same number of items.

```
 d=   [ ['q', 'u', 's', 'a', 'p', 'e', 'a']
     ['500', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'P', '04/12/2011', '' ]
     ['500', 'G', 'G', 'F', 'C', 'P', '04/12/2011', ''] 
     ['5', 'ZUMZ', 'ZUMZ', 'C', 'C', 'B', '04/12/2011', '']
     ['2', 'ZUMZ', 'ZUMZ', 'F', 'C', 'B', '04/12/2011', '']
     ['7', 'ZUMZ', 'ZUMZ', 'M', 'C', 'B', '04/12/2011', '']]
```

Only the first five itmes.

```
 d2=   [ ['q', 'u', 's', 'a', 'p']
         ['500', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'C']
         ['500', 'G', 'G', 'F', 'C'] 
         ['5', 'ZUMZ', 'ZUMZ', 'C', 'C']
         ['2', 'ZUMZ', 'ZUMZ', 'F', 'C']
         ['7', 'ZUMZ', 'ZUMZ', 'M', 'C']]


f = urllib.urlopen(url)
f = csv.reader(f)
d= np.asarray(list(f), dtype= 'object')
print d
m=  d[:,:]                
print m
```

I tried above and m=  d[:,0:5]

Comment: `m= d[:,0:5] ` should return exactly first five columns of an array. what do you get instead?

Comment: @user428862 and @Andrey: The issue is that if your list of lists is (N,M) and you use the object dtype, you get an (N,) array, where each element is a list, rather than an array of M elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
m = np.array([x[:5] for x in d], dtype=object)
```

Although if they are all strings, you should use a string dtype instead.

Comment: @user428862: I didn't mean `dtype=string`, rather a string dtype, which would be something like `dtype='S8'` or `dtype=(str,16)`, etc.

Comment: oh, thanks, would there be a pick in speed, likely more compact, right?